# How to know which VIO is for network and which for storage?

Tags: aix

**Question:** How to know which VIO is for network and which for storage?

besides naming convention, what are the commands/methods to check, what does the VIO do?

Answer (score 0):

You want to check, which VIOS is providing either network or storage for an LPAR? If you want to query this from within the LPAR, for storage, it's easiest to query the kernel directly with `echo cvai|kdb` for VSCSI and `echo vfcs|kdb` for NPIV.

For the networking part, only thing that comes to mind is parsing the output of `entstat -d adaptername` or `netstat -v` but as the virtualised network is not a point-to-point connection, unlike VSCSI or NPIV for example, only way to query this reliably is by using `seastat` on the responsible VIOS. For that, `lscfg -l "en*"` and the location codes shown should provide you with information from which machine/frame the underlying physical adapters are provided. See e.g. [Decoding location codes - Where is my device?](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/aix/library/au-aix-decoding-location-codes/) on developerworks or [Part locations and location codes](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/P8DEA/p8ecs/p8ecs_locations.htm) in IBM Infocenter for more information on those.

But it's probably much easier to just query the responsible HMC for everything you want to know. Find out which one(s) is/are responsible with
`lsrsrc IBM.MCP` and then query on the HMC via [lssyscfg command](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/POWER8/p8edm/lssyscfg.html) or [lshwres command](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/P8DEA/p8edm/lshwres.html) - there are a lot of existing hint pages about both of those.